# Store MATLAB Strings contained in cell array in excel Spreadsheet

Tags: string, excel, matlab, matrix, cell-array

I'm storing MATLAB strings in Excel spreadsheet.

My data is like:

```
Matrix = 
[644x16 char]
[686x16 char]
[569x13 char]
[660x13 char]
[619x13 char]
[599x13 char]
[607x13 char]
[702x13 char]
[633x13 char]
[623x11 char]
[645x11 char]
[697x11 char]
...
```

I want to save these strings in an Excel column. Due to not all the strings having the same number of character, I was forced to store this data on a `cell` array.

Any ideas? Thank you so much mates.

Comment: one cell elemnet shall be put into one line? Can you give an simple example? Does it have to be a excel spreadsheet or is csv file ok?

Comment: Thank you @Steffen A .csv could be fine. The final matrix is a 35330x5 element. 3 columns of numeric data and 2 for 'strings'(identificators).

Cell elements are repeated strings.

Comment: Can you pleas show how the file should look like for Matrix = {['ab';'cd'];['efg';'hij';'klm']}

Comment: Yes, I extract the string information from a .mat file.
for ii = 1 : length(files)
load(strcat(directory,files(ii).name));
M = repmat(ot.name,length(ot.relac),1);
Matrix{:,ii} = M;
end

Comment: Please show how your desired result should look like for my example Matrix. I am still unable to figure out, what you aim for.

Comment: On your example, on the excel or the .csv should be a column like this. ab;cd;efg;hij;klm;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write multiple matrices of different size to an Excel file with `xlswrite`, specify the starting cell for each submatrix:

**xlsWriteMatCell.m**

```
function xlsWriteMatCell(fileName,M)

startCells = cumsum([1 cellfun(@(c)size(c,1),M)]);
startCells(end) = [];
for ic = 1:numel(startCells),
    xlswrite(fileName,M{ic},1,['A' num2str(startCells(ic))]);
end
```

**Test**

```
Matrix = {rand(5,4),rand(6,6),rand(3,3)};
xlsWriteMatCell('test.xlsx',Matrix)
```

[image]

With characters:

```
Matrix = {char(randi(25,5,4)+64),char(randi(25,6,6)+64),char(randi(25,3,3)+64)}
xlsWriteHetro('testChars.xlsx',Matrix)
```

[image]

This will be much slower than writing to a raw csv file, but it will give you an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution suits to my case perfectly. Is slow but efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
% test data
Matrix = {['ab';'cd'];['efg';'hij';'klm']};

fid = fopen('out.csv', 'w');
% For each element of cell
for i = 1:length(Matrix);
   mat = Matrix{i};
   % for each line in cell-element
   for ii = 1:size(mat,1)
       fwrite(fid, mat(ii,:));
       fwrite(fid,';');
   end
end
fclose(fid);
```

Content of output file will be:
ab;cd;efg;hij;klm;

Comment: It works for simple cases. I think is a good option for numeric data bases but not for strings and numbers at the same time. @chppjc option suits on my case perfectly. Thank you for your time and work.